# CV_8UC4 convertTo CV_8UC1 doesn't work

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I got image from kinect v2 with type CV_8UC4.
Now I try to use in in type CV_8UC1 with the following code.

```
cv::Mat mImg(iHeight, iWidth, CV_8UC4);
cv::Mat mImg2(iHeight, iWidth, CV_8UC1);
....
get image from kinect to mImg
....
mImg.convertTo(mImg2, CV_8UC1);
```

After that, mImg2 type is still 24 ( CV_8UC4 ), not sure whether I use this function correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Find some clues from other link.

CV_8UC4 to CV_8UC1 is not channel issue so don't use convertTo.

```
cvtColor(mImg,mImg2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Use cvtColor instead and now the type is changed. Although the image comes to be grey, I think I got the right way.

Comment: be careful what you want to do, if you use CV_BGR2GRAY it will assume 8UC3 input, not 8UC4. CV_BGRA2GRAY will convert 4 channels to one channel. BUT: What do you want to achieve? BGR2GRAY will compute a linear combinatin from all the channels, something like 0.33*r + 0.33*g + 0.33*b (in reality, green and red will be weighted higher than blue channel!). Not sure how exactly the alpha channel will come in there.

Comment: Actually the image is grey now with CV_8UC1 type. I will do further test to replace CV_BGR2GRAY. I just want to say that cvtColor is the right choice for this issue rather than convertTo.

Comment: really depends ob what you want to achieve, but as you found out,  convertTo can't be used to change the number of channels.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what exactly you want to achieve. Kinect probably returns data in form {x,y,depth,somethingelse_forexamplecolor}, so if you wish to get depth data in separate Mat, you'd go with split():

```
vector<cv::Mat> channels(4);
cv::split(mImg, channels);
cv::Mat depth = channels[2]; //or other than 2
```

But you can keep data together, accessing it with:

```
char depth = mImg.at<cv::Vec4b>(x,y)[0];
```